# Empty Vector with nested HashMap in Clojure setup

Tags: clojure

I've just started learning Clojure and I'm attempting to write something to pull some URL's from a web page into memory with some additional meta data around each URL.

I can get the URLs but it's storing them somewhere that I'm having an issue with.  I've figured out I need a vector with nested maps, which I can then add new records to with assoc-in, however since I don't know the URL's I'm not sure how I go about defining my data structure initially.

So for example:

```
(def *comics*
  [{:name "Penny-Arcade"
    :url "http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/"
    :working 0
   }
   {:name "We The Robots"
    :url "http://www.wetherobots.com/"
    :working 0
   }])
```

I'm just not sure how I start the above data structure with no data in it, then add it say initially from a command line arg, then the rest from the website.

If someone can suggest a better way that the above to store the data, please feel free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you want to modify your `*comics*` var from some command line argument - and then modify it even more while "working" on the elements in it.

I would suggest you *don't* do that.

There doesn't seem to be any reason you can't take the comics urls from the command line  and pass them as arguments to a function that does the processing and returns whatever you want from those urls. Doing it that way - that is; functionally, without mutating vars - will definitely be easier to implement in clojure, easier to parallellize and just all out more idiomatic and fun.

Comment: Or you could use STM abstractions like Ref in case you really need to update this data throughout the application flow at various points

Comment: I was thinking I would initially populate the first URL from the command line, then the application would generate many more urls to store.  Another part of the application, using concurrency, would validate those urls still work.  I hadn't reach and understanding if that was possible yet, but STM does sound like it would allow me to do that.

Comment: @Dale from what you're describing it sounds like it needs a recursive function call rather than a mutating store for URLs. You can definitely use refs / atoms etc to build mutating storage, but I wouldn't start from the assumption that that is the best way to go about solving your problem when it's already clear that you don't *need* to.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat I'm trying to picture the recursive method in my head, but wouldn't I end up only ever hitting the first link on each page as it crawls through links between each web page?

Comment: Ok I think i figured the application out using recursion, needs a bit more work but ill mark this as answered because you made me think about the alternatives.  Thanks.